# Python multithreading not executing second function

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to implement a very very basic multithreading app but it is not working as expected. Maybe I am just really bad at programming, but I have been experimenting for hours to figure it out. Essentially I am running two while loops, where they print simple "thread1 started" and "thread2 started" with a small delay.

```
import threading
import time

def do_something():
    while True:
        print "thread 1"
        time.sleep(5)
def do_something2():
    while True:
        print "thread 2"
        time.sleep(0.001)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc = threading.Thread(target = do_something())
    proc.start()
    proc2 = threading.Thread(target=do_something2())
    proc2.start()
```

The results are

```
thread1
thread1
thread1
...
```

at 5 second intervals forever. I expected:

```
thread1
thread 2 
thread 2 
thread 2
....
thread1
thread 2
......
```

Why does the second thread never start?

Comment: This is effectively a typo: you pass the function name with parentheses to `Thread` as `target`, but this causes your script to immediately call the function and tries to assign the function result to `target`. You want to only assign the function itself (i.e. without parentheses) to `target`. I suppose this typo is hard enough to miss - so I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` should be a callable that the thread will call when started, you are not passing the method but are calling it

```
proc = threading.Thread(target=do_something())
```

This calls the method `do_something` in the main thread before passing the result to the thread but the method never returns so the thread is never created. You just need to pass the method without calling it

```
proc = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I can't believe this simple mistake drove me nuts for an entire day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in lines like these:

```
proc = threading.Thread(target = do_something())
```

You're assigning `do_something()` to `target`, but that calls the function. You should instead just assign the function and have the thread call it:

```
proc = threading.Thread(target = do_something)
```